# Cant chain Jquery text effect plugin

Tags: jquery

Trying to get each [TextEffect](http://team.fourdesire.com/playgrounds/texteffects) to run in sequence.

This is my jquery code to run the text effect on each class, one after the other.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".sci-fi1").textEffect(function() { 
            $("sci-fi2").textEffect(function () {
                $(".sci-fi3").textEffect()
            });
        });       
    });
    </script>
```

This is the div that contains the text I want to run the effect on in sequence

```
<div id ="text">
          <br />
        <h2>John </h2>
        <p class="sci-fi1">
            Software Developer
        </p>
        <p class="sci-fi2">
            Web Designer
        </p>
        <p class="sci-fi3">
            Computer Technician
       </p>
</div>
```

For some reason only the first text effect runs,
Have I missed something? can you not chain certain plugins the way I'm attempting?

There was a Event.texteffectend noted on the source page, but I wasn't sure how to implement it or if it was even what I was looking for.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `dot` here `$("sci-fi2")` ([**class selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/))

Also, the way to handle end of the animation in this plugin is to attach  a `texteffectend` listener (by [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).

## JavaScript:

```
$(".sci-fi1").textEffect().on("texteffectend", function(){
    $(".sci-fi2").textEffect().on("texteffectend", function(){
        $(".sci-fi3").textEffect();
    });
});
```

## Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/GnbLB/).

Comment: That's great, thanks,I had tried adding the texteffectend, but I was missing the .on, lesson learned.
Thanks again